# Override default navigation buttons functionality in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

Question is simple: Is there a way to override the behaviour of the default buttons placed in the navigation bar of a `jqGrid` grid?

I'm using the `struts2` plugin and I needed to launch an action if user clicks the add button or the edit button to redirect to another page in which this things are done. I wondered if it was possible to override it's default behaviour as I think it's cleaner than defining myself new "add" and "edit" buttons.

Documentation for adding such new buttons [HERE.](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/NavigatorButtons#Sample)

Comment: the page which you reference adds `alert` button and specify `onClick` event handle. Is it not the answer on your question?

Comment: As I understand, the code explained in the sample would create a new button 'Alert', but I'm asking if it's possible to override the  default add button. I don't know if I'm explaining properly.. I want to override so I don't have to add a new one and I can even use the default add button's icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create first navigator bar using `navigator="true"`, but with `navigatorAdd="false"`,  `navigatorEdit="false"`, `navigatorDelete="false"` and so on (see [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Attributes)). In the way you will have navigator bar without any buttons. Then you add custom buttons with the same icons like standard editing buttons (see [the example](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/NavigatorButtons#Sample) which you referenced). You need uses `icon: 'ui-icon-pencil'` for Edit, `ui-icon-plus` for Add, and `ui-icon-trash` for delete. Inside of `onclick` callback you can place any your custom JavaScript code.

**UPDATED**: The names and the values of `navigatorExtraButtons` are build based on the options of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons#definition) method. I've found additionally [this code](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.grid.struts2.js) which should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to find the attribute list for each entry in navigatorExtraButtons but I found nothing. Where can I find such documentation? In the example mentioned I can see that fields 'title', 'icon', 'topic' and 'caption' are available, but I can't see any explanation about them or what else can I use for this navigator extra buttons.. I'm searching because I need to know the index of the selected cell when the user clicks one of this new buttons I'm adding and maybe there's an attribute for this :)

Comment: @Jorge33212: the names and the values are build based on the options of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons#definition) method. I've found additionally [this code](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.grid.struts2.js) which should help you.

Comment: I've taken a look of the code you linked. I appreciate the help but that's too complex for me, as I don't intend to replace the original plugin's code.. I'd like to know how to launch an struts2 action from the onclick event defined for a jqgrid button.. but maybe I should ask a new question, I'm new to stack overflow.. I used the site for reading only but now I've gathered the courage to post :)

Comment: @Jorge33212: I don't know and don't use struts2 at all. The code fragment which I posted shows clear all options which have `navigatorExtraButtons`: `id`, `title`, `position`, `caption`, `icon`, `topic` and `onclick`. One sees additionally which option of `navigatorExtraButtons` corresponds which option of `navButtonAdd` method. For example the option `icon` corresponds `buttonicon` of `navButtonAdd` and `onclick` corresponds `onClickButton`. It was the answer on your additional question about the names of `navigatorExtraButtons` attributes.

Comment: Indeed, thank you so much. I don't know if I should give your answer as accepted or post a new one explaining a bit more on the research I've made to this point.